# Left(null,5) <> 'anything' is not true? [T-SQL]

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

In the last `select` statement below, why is it that "left(null,8) <> 'anything'‌ " is not true with ansi_nulls set off?

I'm trying to find a way to avoid counterintuitive null comparison results like this, without having to use isnull() or coalesce() everwhere in my script. 
‌‌
 ‌

```
 set ansi_nulls off
  s‌elect 'true' where null <> 'anything'  ----> This returns 'true'
  s‌elect 'true' where left(null,8) = null  ----> This returns 'true'
  s‌elect 'true' where left(null,8) <> 'anything'‌ ----> **This returns nothing**
‌‌
```

Comment: With ANSI `NULL`s off, `NULL` is treated as a legitimate value rather than an indeterminate value.  Hence, all these make sense.  You would have to show your queries and what you actually want, if you want advice.

Comment: If Null is a legit value, I would expect `left(null,8)` to not equal `anything`, and therefore the 3rd statement would return `true`. But it doesn't. Am I missing something?

Comment: I suggest you stick with the ANSI/ISO SQL standard behavior and code your queries accordingly. Otherwise, you will be bitten when you try to use features like filtered indexes, indexes on computed columns, indexed views, etc. Also, note that `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` is deprecated and [will generate and error in a future SQL Server version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql).

Comment: [SET ANSI_NULLS ON affects a comparison only if one of the operands of the comparison is either a variable that is NULL or a literal NULL. If both sides of the comparison are columns or compound expressions, the setting does not affect the comparison.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

Always use **isnull** regardless of whether the ansi_nulls is  on or off

```
  select 'true' where  isnull( left(null ,8) , '') <> 'anything' ----> This returns 'true'
```

Always use **isnull** regardless of whether the ansi_nulls is  on or off

```
  select 'true' where  isnull( left(null ,8) , '') <> 'anything' ----> This returns 'true'
```

***Modification***

Thanks **Gordon Linoff**

then use **COALESCE** And don t use isnull

```
select 'true' where  COALESCE ( left(null ,8) , '') <> 'anything' ----> This returns 'true'
```

Comment: *Don't* use `isnull()`  -- ever if you can avoid it.  SQL offers `IS NULL` and `COALESCE()` as standard functions/operators.